# Security Enabled Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Does anyone know what Security Enabled in Microsoft Teams is? I used the MS GRAPH API to connect and it returned a column named security enabled with a true or false

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Teams](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/teams_api_overview) is built on top of [Groups](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group#properties). The `securityEnabled` property is inherited from the `Group` object:

> Specifies whether the group is a **security group**. If the `mailEnabled` property is also `true`, the group is a **mail-enabled security group**; otherwise it is a security group. Must be false for Office 365 groups.